# Expression blend photoshop effects

Tags: silverlight, import, photoshop, expression-blend

I'm new to using blend, I've discovered when I import my photoshop file blend takes my effects away. Can anyone tell me why blend doesn't recognize my effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effects are often custom within each product and are probably outside of the scope of whoever made the PhotoShop to Blend converter however Blend/Silverlight has a pretty cool shader capability.

For things like DropShadow and Blur you can easily recreate with the default effects in Blend with a drag and drop from Blend's Asset panel.

If you want more effects, I've used the [Windows Presentation Foundation Pixel Shader Effects Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/) which works fine in Silverlight. Compile, Add the DLL to your Silverlight project and you should see the Effects in you Assets panel, ready to drag and drop on your imported XAML elements.

One that I often use, especially for animations is the DirectionalBlur for motion-blurring. They also have Magnify and some color effects.

Comment: I've also manually re-added effects like DropShadow to content that was imported from Illustrator, it worked fine for me.